# Integrating Netbeans with phpunit not finding skeleton generator

Tags: netbeans, phpunit, integration

I have netbeans 7.1.2 and installed phpunit and skeleton generator the same as told in [documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html?print=yes#installing-phpunit).
In netbeans options, in tab of phpunit there is no field for adding skeleton generator script and when trying to generate the tests a warning is shown saying that tests where not generated. see the console.
in the console is written:

PHPUnit 3.7.9 by Sebastian Bergmann.

unrecognized option --skeleton-test

is there anyway to tell netbeans where is the skeleton script?

Comment: Actually error:
unrecognized option --skeleton-test
is the result when I try "phpunit --skeleon-test" in command line
but skeleton is installed... more confused!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is just for the version of netbeans. install the netbeans 7.2.1 and everything would be ok.

Comment: using 7.2 but can't find? any help Please

Comment: I am using Netbeans Version 8.0.1. Still facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Try this for MAMP

sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/pear install phpunit/DbUnit phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator phpunit/PHPUnit_Story

PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator-1.2.0 gets installed in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/
then select the `phpunit-skelgen` in netbeans