# getting this error: unrecognized option --skeleton-test using PHPUnit 3.7.10 using Netbeans 7.1.2

Tags: unit-testing, netbeans-7

I have installed PHPUnit via pear installer  - but I'm having trouble getting it to work get this error when using Tools> Create PHPUnit Tests

[image]

The output error is: PHPUnit 3.7.10 by Sebastian Bergmann. unrecognized option --skeleton-test

This is the Unit Testing tab in Netbeans:

[image]

Tried different include paths in the General Tab but not sure how to include the classes

Any ideas what is wrong...? thanks

Comment: See that link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600050/integrating-netbeans-with-phpunit-not-finding-skeleton-generator

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the phpunit-skelgen file exists in the same directory as the phpunit binary (C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\ in your installation).

If not, install the PHPUnit SkeletonGenerator the same way you installed PHPUnit, eg from PEAR:

C:\wamp\bin\pear.exe install phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator